# Clean API after Content Type modification

Tags: strapi

During development, I made quite a few changes to my model. Since Strapi doesn't migrate your db this results in an API with lots of confusing and useless fields (that are not in the admin UI), like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI1yv.png).

The migration/database problem is a [well known issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1114). However, is it possible to clean the API without fixing the database (which I don't really care if the API is clean) ? Ideally the API should mirror the admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the created_by and updated_by we have an open issue to hide these by default, it's being looked into by our engineering team: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/7177

Can you clarify what fields in your screenshot you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I meant for example the date fields : Date, date and day. They are the results of modifiying the content type, but in the admin panel only "day" is present. It is true for most other "null" fields. I am totally fine with created_at and updated_at, they are quite common and useful.